# How to set up http timeout when requesting metaplex findbymint

Tags: metaplex-js

Some rpc calls using metaplex SDK metaplex.nft.findByMint seem to get stuck, is it possible to specify to solana/web3 or metaplex SDK the timeout by default?

EDIT:
I finally could set timeout by sending abortController directly ass a paramater

Answer (score 1):

yes do something like:

```
import * as https from "https"

const agent = new https.agent({keepAlive: true, timeout: 99999})     
const connection = new Connection("your rpc", {httpAgent: agent})
```

and finally initialize metaplex using this:

```
metaplex.make(connection)
```